# Client is getting 'Connection Refused' when trying to Connect Indy 10 Server

Tags: delphi, connection, indy

We have recently released a Server that is written in Delphi 2010 using an Indy 10 TIdTCPServer. Remote Field Engineers connect to the Server on a predefined port using their Smart Phones. We have one particular Customer that tells us that after a certain period of time (1 day, 2 days) etc that the Client gets an ECONNREFUSED (ConnectionRefused) on his device. At this point none of the remote engineers can connect to the server. Anybody got any idea as to why this may be the case?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Con.

Answer (score 1):

My initial suspicion is a deadlock in the event handlers for OnConnection OnExecute or OnDisconnect.

Are you synchronising corectly across the connection contexts(threads)?

But you need to post your server code so we can check it.

Comment: There is quite a bit of code for the OnConnection, OnExecute and OnDisconnect events. I have a TreeView that is Updated when to show what the thread is doing. I use a TidNotify class to do this. I thought that it was only Updates to my data and the interface that I had to synchronise, thinking that Indy handled the connection contexts synchronisation?

Comment: @CMB I highly recommend to make the server a Windows service type application without any GUI. Move the TreeView stuff into a separate application which uses a REST based client interface to get the needed information for display. This will avoid nasty VCL concurrency problems completely.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused my intermittent outage on the network and the software is failing to access database tables across the network

Answer (score 1):

`ECONNREFUSED` means one of two possible things:

1. there is no server socket listening on the IP/Port being connected to.
2. there is a server listening, but its backlog of pending connections is full and cannot accept the new client's request to connect at that moment.

For #1, verify with a port viewing tool, such as NETSTAT or TCPView, that your server is still running and that is listening port is still open and in the LISTENING state.

For #2, check if your server's `OnListenException` event is getting triggered, which would indicate the server is having problems accepting connections from its backlog.

Comment: The OnListenException event was not triggered but the Customer restarted the application before running NetStat as instructed. Looks like it must be #1. Awaiting further info